# Execute a script on f:ajax "success" event only when validation has not failed

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf-2, event-handling, composite-component

I have created a composite component that extends the command button and add some ajax functions (onBegin, onComplete and onSuccess), but I have some problems that I couldnt solve:

When I click on the button and a validation error occur, in success event function is passed #{facesContext.validationFailed} = false instead of true even thought the form is render again; (html is render before a success event called, right?)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<cc:interface shortDescription="CommandButton com Ajax">

    <cc:attribute name="onbegin"/>
    <cc:attribute name="oncomplete"/>
    <cc:attribute name="onsuccess"/>
    <cc:attribute name="render"/>
    <cc:attribute name="execute"/>
    <cc:attribute name="action" targets="commandButton"/>
    <cc:attribute name="actionListener" targets="commandButton"/>
    <cc:attribute name="value"/>
    <cc:attribute name="styleClass" targets="commandButton"/>
    <cc:attribute name="immediate" targets="commandButton"/>

</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <h:outputScript library="progutils" name="/js/commandButton.js" target="HEAD"/>

    <h:commandButton id="commandButton" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
        <f:ajax render="#{cc.attrs.render}" execute="#{cc.attrs.execute}"
                onevent="function(data){execCommandButtonAjax(data, function(){ #{cc.attrs.onbegin} },function(){ #{cc.attrs.oncomplete} },function(){ #{cc.attrs.onsuccess} }, #{facesContext.validationFailed})}">
        </f:ajax>
    </h:commandButton>

</cc:implementation>

</html>
```

Javascript File

```
function execCommandButtonAjax(data, onBegin, onComplete, onSuccess, validationFailed) {
    var status = data.status;
    switch (status) {
        case 'begin': {
            onBegin();
            break;
        }
        case 'complete': {
            onComplete();
            break;
        }
        case 'success': {
            console.log('Validation Failed ' + validationFailed);
            if(!validationFailed){
                onSuccess();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Using the component:

```
<pu2:commandButton id="btnPu2" 
                   onbegin="block(); console.log('begin')"                                                                    
                   oncomplete="unblock(); console.log('complete')"
                   onsuccess="console.log('success')"
                   execute="@form"
                   action="#{list.search()}"
                   render="@form :table-form :form-pagination"
                   value="Do it">
</pu2:commandButton>
```

Comment: 1 question per question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL expressions are evaluated while generating HTML output. They are not evaluated during JavaScript events or so. Rightclick and *View Source*. You see, it's one and all HTML/JS. No JSF components, no EL expressions. JSF is "just" a HTML code generator.

So when you load the page, `#{facesContext.validationFailed}` will print `false`. **Exactly this value** is being passed as JS function argument. It will only work if you re-render the JSF component responsible for printing `#{facesContext.validationFailed}` before passing it as JS function argument.

Standard JSF offers no facilities to pass additional information to the ajax response. Component libraries like PrimeFaces and OmniFaces support this via a custom `PartialViewContext`. PrimeFaces has even a builtin `validationFailed` property in its `args` object which is available in any `oncomplete` attribute.

Your best bet is to conditionally render `onsuccess` script itself.

```
<h:commandButton id="commandButton" value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
    <f:ajax execute="#{cc.attrs.execute}" render="#{cc.attrs.render} onsuccess" 
            onevent="function(data){execCommandButtonAjax(data, function(){ #{cc.attrs.onbegin} },function(){ #{cc.attrs.oncomplete} })}">
    </f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
<h:panelGroup id="onsuccess">
    <h:outputScript rendered="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
        #{cc.attrs.onsucces}
    </h:outputScript>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I see, the #{facesContext.validationFailed} print true because the button has a render="@form" ( and the button is inside the form), but is passed to javascript function the value false, probably because when the function is called the value false was printed.