# JSF Condition in oncomplete not executed

Tags: jsf, backing-beans

I have below code that should be executed after actionListener. But it seems that even though isValid in my backing bean is set to true, goToHomePage() was not execute.

```
oncomplete="if (#{user.isValid()}) { goToHomePage(); };"
```

Can somebody explain to me why? And what's the correct way to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute a script on f:ajax "success" event only when validation has not failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30788402/execute-a-script-on-fajax-success-event-only-when-validation-has-not-failed)

Comment: if() and goToHomePage() are JavaScript. `#{user.isValid()}` is a EL-expression and was evaluated with the last render of this HTML-block. Because `if(..)` is JavaScript, the value of `#{user.isValid()}` must evaluate to something that results in a legal JavaScript-if. I.e. the string "true"  -> `if(true) { goToHomePage();}`.